# Cookies problem in ASP.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies

I am currently working on an ASP.net c# web application. I am trying to use a cookie which will store the users id number from the database.

I set the cookie when the user logs in using the following code:

```
Response.Cookies["userID"].Value = reader.GetString("use_id");
```

When the user logs in it does a Response.Redirect to /software/index.aspx.

This file then retrieves the value of the cookie with the following code

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["userID"].Value
```

When I then click a link to a different page e.g. ../accounts/index.aspx and I try to run the same code to get the value of the cookie, the value is empty.

What am I doing wrong.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: Double check and make sure that on all requests for the cookie, you are using Request.Cookie, not Response.Cookie.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the Add method on the cookies collection and see if it makes a difference:

```
Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie("userID")
        {
            Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1),
            Value = reader.GetString("use_id"),
            HttpOnly = true
        });
```

Edit: Typos.

Comment: I have tried this but it still shows it as blank when I try to access it from another page and @Shiraz Bhaiji it is on the same website its just in a different directory, i.e. read first in /software/index.aspx and then read again in ../accounts/index.aspx.

Comment: just found that if I add path = "/pathtoapplication" works fine without requiring the expires parameter. Thanks for your help both of you

Answer (score 1):

Have you set an expiry time on the cookie?

Is the index.aspx a page on the same site that gave you the cookie?